# PloneFormGen Mailer Sending Duplicated Emails

Tags: plone, ploneformgen, plone-3.x

I have a Plone 3.2.1 site with Products.PloneFormGen installed on it, it has a form which is configured with a mailer that sends to a Google Apps distribution group. The form, once submitted is meant to send out one email to the distribution group, however; at the moment it is sending 4.

To debug and make sure it wasn't the distribution group doing something weird,  I installed Products.PrintingMailHost on the site and can see the email printed 4 times in the console each time the form is submitted. It was suggested to me that the issue might be related to Zope Database ConflictErrors, however I see nothing related to that when loading any of my clients in foreground mode, leading me to believe this might not be the problem, or I am looking in the wrong place.

If I remove the mailer apater from the form, it prevents it sending any email at all.

If it will help, I have included the output when I load one of my clients in foreground mode:

```
$ bin/client1 fg
/usr/local/plone/zeocluster/parts/client1/bin/runzope -X debug-mode=on
2013-12-04 13:37:16 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Wed Dec  4 13:37:16 2013
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 8080
2013-12-04 13:37:16 INFO Zope Set effective user to "plone"
2013-12-04 13:37:17 INFO Marshall libxml2-python not available. Unable to register libxml2 based marshallers.
Hold on to your hats folks, I'm a-patchin'
2013-12-04 13:37:19 WARNING PrintingMailHost 

******************************************************************************

Monkey patching MailHosts to print emails to the terminal instead of
sending them.

NO MAIL WILL BE SENT FROM ZOPE AT ALL!

Turn off debug mode or remove PrintingMailHost from the Products
directory to turn this off.

******************************************************************************

2013-12-04 13:37:19 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage (1534) ClientStorage (pid=1534) created RW/normal for storage: '1'
2013-12-04 13:37:19 INFO ZEO.cache created temporary cache file '<fdopen>'
2013-12-04 13:37:19 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage (1534) Testing connection <ManagedClientConnection ('127.0.0.1', 8100)>
2013-12-04 13:37:19 INFO ZEO.zrpc.Connection(C) (127.0.0.1:8100) received handshake 'Z303'
2013-12-04 13:37:19 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage (1534) Server authentication protocol None
2013-12-04 13:37:19 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage (1534) Connected to storage: ('localhost', 8100)
2013-12-04 13:37:19 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage (1534) Verifying cache
2013-12-04 13:37:19 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage (1534) endVerify finishing
2013-12-04 13:37:19 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage (1534) endVerify finished
2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/Zope-2.10.7-final-py2.4/lib/python/zope/app/locales/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/zope.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/sv/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/de/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/fr/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/da/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/it/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/pl/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/en/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/cs/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/uk/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:20 WARNING PlacelessTranslationService Error while compiling /usr/local/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/quintagroup.captcha.core-0.4.1-py2.4.egg/quintagroup/captcha/core/locales/ja/LC_MESSAGES/quintagroup.captcha.core.po 

2013-12-04 13:37:22 INFO Plone Python does not have SSL support. OpenID support not available
2013-12-04 13:37:22 INFO collective.monkeypatcher Monkey patching Products.CMFPlone.PloneTool.PloneTool.listMetaTags with quintagroup.seoptimizer.listMetaTags.qsListMetaTags
2013-12-04 13:37:22 INFO collective.monkeypatcher Monkey patching Products.CMFPlone.PloneTool.PloneTool.listMetaTagsOriginal with quintagroup.seoptimizer.listMetaTags.qsListMetaTagsOriginal
2013-12-04 13:37:24 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'collective.fancyzoomview' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:24 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'ilrt.contentmigrator' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:25 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.Andreas00Theme' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:25 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.AROfficeTransforms' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:25 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.CHZenlike' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:25 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.feedfeeder' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:25 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.FlashVideo' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:26 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.PloneHotfix20110720' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:26 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.qPloneSkinSchools' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:26 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'Products.qPloneSkinWhiteBlack' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:26 INFO PlacelessTranslationService You have a stale entry for 'webcouturier.dropdownmenu' in your ZMI Products section.You should consider removing it. 

2013-12-04 13:37:27 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests
```

### Contents of client1/event.log

```
------
2013-12-04T15:59:25 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formmaileradapter.2013-03-07.2473418839' is missing; ignored.
------
2013-12-04T15:59:25 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formmaileradapter.2013-03-07.1334448370' is missing; ignored.
------
2013-12-04T15:59:25 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'mailer-1' is missing; ignored.
------
2013-12-04T15:59:25 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formmaileradapter.2013-03-07.3779688594' is missing; ignored.
------
2013-12-04T15:59:25 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formcustomscriptadapter.2013-12-04.3934224717' is missing; ignored.
------
2013-12-04T15:59:25 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formmaileradapter.2013-12-04.4414621583' is missing; ignored.
------
2013-12-04T15:59:25 INFO Plone  
CMFPlone/skins/plone_scripts/getWorkflowHistory: http://xxxxxxx:8080/xxxx/contact-us/thank-you has no associated workflow
```

Comment: @SteveM I checked zeoserver.log but couldn't see anything being inserted into it when I hit 'submit' to receive my 4 emails, but I checked in client1/event.log and have edited my question to show the contents - looks like it's checking for other mailers which it can't find, would that cause this issue?

Comment: Those messages are completely harmless. It just means that one or more form folders have references to deleted mailers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing and saving the form.  That may get rid of the warnings about missing action adapters.

In that edit form have a look at the selected action adapters and see if there are any extra adapters there that you do not expect. But it sounds like you may have already done that.

If it is a short form: simply recreate it and remove the old one. :-)

I wonder if the form has remembered some action adapters that are no longer available but that are found anyway using acquisition.  This is a long shot. ;-)

Check the mailer adapter. Maybe you have some overrides that add too many email addresses? Maybe the recipients are in the To, Cc and Bcc fields?

Comment: Thanks @maurtis, recreating the form fixed the issue. I'm not sure what was causing it as I had no overrides on the mailer adapter, personally I think the acquisition point you raised might actually be the case!